# h2 text is blue but should be black

Tags: html, css

My h2 class="post-title" text is blue and should be black. Please can someone help?

Also, .cat-title should be sitting on top of the image and should have a blue background. It seemed to work before I made some changes.

```css
/* General ------------------------- */

html {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('../img/bgimage.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font: 1em/1.5"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  /*background-color: #d1c5b7;*/
  width: 1225px;
  background-color: white;
}
#wrapper {
  /*max-width: 940px;*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*padding: 0 5%;*/
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* Heading ------------------------- */

header {
  /*padding-top: 10px;*/
  height: 140px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #856941;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 5rem;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 2px black;
}
/* Navigation ------------------------- */

nav {
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
nav a {
  line-height: 43px;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  color: white;
}
/* Articles ----------------------- */

.row {
  width: 1228px;
  height: 1983px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  margin-right: -25px;
  margin-left: -25px;
}
.main-content {
  width: 702px;
  height: 2129px;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}
section {
  margin: 20px;
}
.row-listing {
  width: 752;
  height: 2090;
  margin-left: -25px;
  margin-right: -25px;
}
.column-half {
  width: 326px;
  height: 310px;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}
. .cat-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: #487be4;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
img {
  width: 326px;
  height: 172px;
}
.meta {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -12px;
  width: 312px;
  height: 25px;
  padding-left: 14px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #a6a6a6;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.post-title {
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.3;
  padding-left: 14px;
  margin: 7px 0;
}
/* Sidebar ------------------------ */

.sidebar {
  width: 376px;
  height: 1983px;
  border-left: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
}
/* Footer ------------------------- */

footer {
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
  padding-top: 50px;
  color: #ccc;
  background-color: #735d41;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Live Wire | Beta</title>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <a href="index.html" id="logo">
      <h1>Live Wire</h1>
    </a>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="tech.html">Tech</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="entertainment.html">Entertainment</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="science.html">Science</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="geek.html">Geek</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="howto.html">How To</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="more.html">More</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="news.html">News</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <nav>
  </header>
  <div #wrapper>
    <div class="row">
      <section class="main-content">
        <div class="row-listing">
          <div class="column-half">
            <article class="Chrome Ram">
              <span class="cat-title">Technology</span> 
              <a href="articles/article001.html">
                <img src="img/chrome.jpg" alt="Chrome">
              </a>
              <div class="meta">
                <time>1 October, 2015</time>
              </div>
              <h2 class="post-title">
         <a href="articles/article001.htm">How to Stop Chrome from Eating your Ram</a>
        </h2>
              <div class="excerpt">
              </div>
            </article>
          </div>
          <!-- END OF COLUMN HALF -->
          <div class="column-half">
            <article class="CSS Boxes">
              <span class="cat-title">
         Technology
        </span> 
              <a href="articles/article002.html">
                <img src="img/css_box_model.gif" alt="CSS Box Model">
              </a>
              <div class="meta">
                <time>1 October, 2015</time>
              </div>
              <h2 class="post-title">
         <a href="articles/article002.htm">CSS Boxes</a>
        </h2>
              <div class="excerpt">
              </div>
            </article>
          </div>
          <!-- END OF COLUMN HALF -->
          <div class="column-half">
            <article class="CSS Layout">
              <span class="cat-title">
         Technology
        </span> 
              <a href="articles/article003.html">
                <img src="img/cssImage.jpg" alt="CSS 3 Image">
              </a>
              <div class="meta">
              </div>
              <h2 class="post-title">
         <a href="articles/article003.htm">CSS Layout</a>
        </h2>
              <div class="excerpt">
              </div>
            </article>
          </div>
          <!-- END OF COLUMN HALF -->
          <div class="column-half">
            <article class="HTML and CSS Book">
              <span class="cat-title">
         Technology
        </span> 
              <a href="articles/article004.html">
                <img src="img/book.jpg" alt="Book Image">
              </a>
              <div class="meta">
              </div>
              <h2 class="post-title">
         <a href="articles/article004.htm">The Best Book for HTML & CSS Beginners</a>
        </h2>
              <div class="excerpt">
              </div>
            </article>
          </div>
          <!-- END OF COLUMN HALF -->
        </div>
        <!-- END OF ROW LISTING -->
      </section>
      <aside class="sidebar">
      </aside>
    </div>
    <!-- end of row -->
  </div>
  <!-- end of wrapper -->
  <footer>
    <p>&copy; 2015 Sean Blythe</p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your style sheet has " . .cat-title". The extra dot is breaking your style. And the comments below are correct <a> tags are blue by default. You have to style the <a> tag directly to override the default. I'd really recommend learning to use the developer tools in chrome or Firebug plugin for Firefox. It's easy to see these types of issues that way.

Comment: I'm using chrome developer tools, still a beginner though. Will try and find a tutorial on how to use developer tools properly though. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's blue because it's an `a` tag. Try targeting the color like this:

```
.post-title a {
    color: black;
}
```

I'm not sure about your second issue, but you have an extra `.` in your css. Should be `.cat-title` instead of `..cat-title`

Comment: Problem solved on second issue. Got rid of top: o; in .cat-title

Answer (score 1):

do this `a` as default have a blue color

```
h2.post-title a{
    color: #000;
}
```